# Camera Module "Delock 9599" works for only a few seconds!

Tags: 16.04, video, webcam, camera

I am trying to use the Delock 9599 Camera with linux. It works for a second or two then stops.

When motion is made infront of the Camera, like a hand jesture, (without recording) then it stops working. I reduced the Camera frame to the lowest setting and it works for maybe 3 or 4 seconds. I tried it with a few drivers and with all of them it is the same scenario.

When I tried connecting other cameras with similar video output, it operated without a hitch.

Can someone suggest any work around?